# Editing file in TCL and writing the revised contents to an output file

Tags: tcl

I have an input file fI as follows :-

#### module c1

```
accent {a1} {Z} ;# net:n1551 , little:big
accent {a2} {C} ;# net:n1536 , little:big
```

#### module c2

```
accent {a3} {Z} ;# net:n1552 , little:big
accent {a4} {C} ;# net:n1537 , little:big
```

I want to manipulate this input file and get the output file fO as follows:-

```
accord [get_pins c1/a1/Z] [get_nets c1/n1551]
accord [get_pins c1/a2/C] [get_nets c1/n1536]

accord [get_pins c2/a3/Z] [get_nets c2/n1552]
accord [get_pins c2/a4/C] [get_nets c2/n1537]
```

How can i do this in TCL ? Please help .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "fI" and "fO" are actual file names:

```
set fi [open fI]
set fo [open fO w]
set module {}
while {[chan gets $fi line] >= 0} {
    if {[string is space $line]} continue

    switch -- [lindex $line 0] {
        module {set module [lindex $line 1]}
        accent {
            if {[regexp {{(\w+)}.+{(\w+)}.+:(\w+) ,} $line -> a b c]} {
                chan puts $fo "accord \[get_pins $module/$a/$b] \[get_nets $module/$c]"
            }
        }
    }
}
chan close $fi
chan close $fo
```

Documentation: [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, there was a mistake in the question , it should be c2  for get_nets in module c2. Is there also  a way to use file read and write in tcl for this  question ?

Comment: @NishaJohn: see updated answer. I tested the code I posted first, but this code is untested (but ought to work).

Comment: i still had another question with the same issue, if possible can you help ?if it is like this , how can i write the code, i tried with the lindex  , but it doesn't work for me #===============================================
#             module c1
# ===============================================

Comment: @NishaJohn: I don't understand your problem. I think it would be best if you opened another question and described what you are trying to do and how it fails there.